# Postgres GIN Index Performance Degregation

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, rds

I have a Postgres `GIN` index on a table, `t1`, over a `JSONB` column `a_col`.

`CREATE INDEX i_1 ON t1 USING gin (t1.a_col)`

This takes a query runtime of ~2s down to ~50ms.

This table is somewhat active, taking ~1k new rows of data daily with no updates/deletes.

The problem I am seeing is the performance of this index dramatically falls off after a few hundred writes - query performance falls back to ~2s.

The issue is resolved after running a `reindex` operation.

`REINDEX INDEX i_1`

But this leaves the question what is driving the index to run so poorly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running

`select * from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 't1'`

I was seeing that `n_mod_since_analyze` had >2k rows and `last_autoanalyze` was several days out.

By dropping the value of `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` from `0.05` to `0.002`, `autoanalyze` began to run move frequently and started to see more consistent performance.

Comment: Rather than setting the scale factor so low, consider setting it to 0 and use a high `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` that corresponds to your daily change rate. Are you sure that an `ANALYZE` fixed your issue (i.e. it was caused by a bad plan) and not a `VACUUM`?

Comment: My understanding is that `VACUUM` would "reclaim storage occupied by dead tuples" that are "deleted or obsoleted by an update" which happens on "frequently-updated tables" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-vacuum.html). This particular tables sees a lot of inserts, but no updates/deletes. Thus thus focus on `ANALYZE`. Is that bad logic/thinking/approach?

Comment: No, it isn't. I was thinking that the *GIN pending list* might be a problem.

Comment: Oh got it. The idea being using a fixed value (autovacuum_analyze_threshold) vs a ratio on an ever growing table (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor) to better manage frequency of fire for the index "cleanup"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to suggest.

Comment: Makes sense - this is why I posted - to get different/better ideas - thanks!